# How can I add background for legend with this shape?

Tags: plotting, legending

How can I make a background for legend like this? 
 It's not necessary to be exact the same but something similar that fits the content is good. Or please suggest if you have any idea to make it look better. 
 I'm going to put it inside some plot with grids that is why I need the background to make it better. 
 I also need to make the background fits the content.

[image]

```
ClearAll[legend1]
Options[legend1] = {Joined -> Automatic};
legend1[colors_, polymarkers_, legend__, , OptionsPattern[]] := 
 PointLegend[colors, legend, Joined -> OptionValue[Joined], 
  LegendMarkers -> (ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][#, Offset[4], 
       EdgeForm[]] & /@ polymarkers), LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 30}, 
  LegendLayout -> (Column[
      Grid[{##}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}] & /@ #, 
      Spacings -> -1] &)]
colors = ColorData[97, #] & /@ Range[6];
polymarkers = {"DownTriangle", "SevenPointedStar", "FourPointedStar", 
   "Diamond"};
mylegend = 
  MaTeX[TeXForm[#], Magnification -> 0.5] & /@ {{"5X", "6Y", "8Z", 
     "9M", "2K", "2N", "2T", "3N", "5O"}, {"1X", "3Y", "5Z", "2L", 
     "9K", "3Z", "7X", "3P", "2T"}, {"3K", "6M"}, {"3H", "6K"}, {"X4",
      "Y5", "C6", "1K"}, {"X6", "Y6", "C6", "Z6"}};
legend1[colors, polymarkers, mylegend, , Joined -> True]
```

**EDIT:**
For reference, I'll put the legend in a plot like this.
[image]

```
Legended[Plot[{x, 2 x - 1.5, x - 1, 1 - x, x - 2, 1/2 x - 1}, {x, 1, 
   5}, GridLines -> {Range[1, 5, 1], Range[1, 5, 1]},
  PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {0, 5}},ImageSize -> 360], 
 Placed[legend1[colors, polymarkers, mylegend, , 
   Joined -> True ], {0.2, 0.8}]]
```

Comment: Since you also ask for our opinion: Personally, I wouldn't use a background that fits the content. What about: ``PointLegend[ ..., LegendFunction -> "Panel"]``?

Comment: @Domen I don't have much space to put a rectagular panel like that as I showed with the plot above where the legend is placed on. If you put the rectangular panel it would hide my lines which is not desired.

Comment: @Domen after all, I have to accept that no background looks better but it's also good to know how to make background.

Comment: Glad to hear we've reached an aesthetic consensus :-) I still think "Panel" might look the best, together with fiddling the position of the legend or the aspect ratio of the plot or the plot range ... to get it not to overlap with the curves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set background color to `Row` inside `LegendLayout`:

```
LegendLayout -> (Column[Row[##, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
       Background -> LightGray] & /@ #, Spacings -> -1] &)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make straight lines between 1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6 lines? That would make it much nicer.

Comment: Use ``Partition`` to group legend elements by 2: ``LegendLayout -> (Column[Row[{Grid[##, Spacings -> {1, -1}, Alignment -> {Left, Left}]}, Background -> LightGray] & /@ Partition[#, 2], Spacings -> -1] &)]``

Comment: I just tried this after  a long running like 20 minutes. The plot seems ok but there are two problems with it. 1. It removes the center layout of the text and the marker that I have before. 2. How can I remove the bold outline?

Comment: @hana, I don't quite understand your two problems. Can you please post a screenshot of the result and show where the problems are?

Comment: Sorry I just changed to `Alignment -> {Center, Center}` and it works now.

Comment: J just changed to this `Background -> Opacity[0.1, Gray]` and I got the problem that outline appears between partitions. How can I remove that? I want to use Opacity to make it less gray.   https://ibb.co/bsx8HKD

Comment: Don't use opacity (if you don't really need it). Use ``Background -> GrayLevel[.95]`` to get a lighter gray.

Answer (score 2):

Add `Dividers`?

```
LegendLayout -> (Column[
    Grid[{##}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
       Background -> LightGray] & /@ #, Spacings -> -1, 
    Dividers -> {None, {3 -> Blue, -3 -> Blue}}] &)
```

[image]

Or just ?

```
LegendLayout -> (Column[
    Grid[{##}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}] & /@ #, Spacings -> -1, 
    Dividers -> {None, {3 -> Blue, -3 -> Blue}}, 
    Background -> LightGray] &)
```

Comment: Would it possible to specify the shape myselft with polygon? I don't want to group pairs like that as they are not supposed to grouped.

Comment: @hana  Maybe use the setting by @Domen  `LegendLayout -> (Column[
    Row[{Grid[##, Spacings -> {1, -1}, Alignment -> {Left, Left}, 
         Dividers -> {{-1 -> True}, {-1 -> True}}]}, 
       Background -> LightGray] & /@ Partition[#, 2], 
    Spacings -> .03] &)`

Comment: That seems ok but there are two problems with it. 1. It removes the center layout of the text and the marker that I have before. 2. How can I remove the bold outline?